# Filtering an array of objects Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of objects and Im trying to filter by matching ids

```
//Vehicle is added to quote
function filterByID(item) {
    return item.id === 1;
}
this.vehicle = this.data.filter(filterByID);
```

data is as follows:

```
data: [
    0: {
     id: 0,
     name: name
   },
   1: {
     id: 1,
     name: name
   },
   2: {
     id: 2,
     name: name
   }
]
```

Im getting an empty error when I check the vehicle part

Comment: What's your error, I don't get one when I test?

Comment: please provide the whole component code

Comment: There is no error , it simply returns empty

Comment: the problem doesn't happen if you work with pure js, but i think the problem comes from the life cycle of the component

Comment: Are you sure there is an object with id 1 inside `data`? Can you `console.log(this.data)` the line before filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using it like this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: '',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: '',
  },
];

function filterByID(item) {
  return item.id === 1;
}

console.log(data.filter(filterByID)); // output: [{ "id": 1, "name": "" }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't always need to define a separate function, you can use an arrow function, as below.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 0,
    name: name
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: name
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: name
  }
]

const vehicle = data.filter(item => item.id === 1);

console.log(vehicle);
```

This works fine in pure JS, it looks like it might be an issue with the lifecycle or state of your application. Use `console.log` to make sure that `this.data` is what you expect it to be